# Multiple startActivityForResult()

Tags: java, android

I need to call this function twice in my application pointing to two different activities. I have a unique request code for each call, however my app seems to crash everytime it launches the **second** activity.

Here is my code (only relevant parts): 
MainActivity:

```
//Request Info vars
static final int GET_DETAILS = 1;
static final int EDIT_DETAILS = 2;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            lat = latLng.latitude;
            lon = latLng.longitude;

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MapsActivity.this,NewMarkerActivity.class), GET_DETAILS);

        }
    });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            current_marker = marker;

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MapsActivity.this,EditMarkerActivity.class), EDIT_DETAILS);
        }
    });





}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GET_DETAILS) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String marker_title=data.getStringExtra("title");
            String marker_snippet = data.getStringExtra("snippet");

            addMarker(lat, lon, marker_title, marker_snippet);


            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));

        }
    } if (requestCode == EDIT_DETAILS) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {    
            String marker_title=data.getStringExtra("title");
            String marker_snippet = data.getStringExtra("snippet");

            current_marker.setTitle(marker_title);
            current_marker.setSnippet(marker_snippet);
          }

        }
    }
```

EditMarkerActivity:

```
    public class EditMarkerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_marker_activity);

        Button save_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
                String marker_title = editName.getText().toString();

                EditText editSnippet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSnippet);
                String marker_snippet = editSnippet.getText().toString();



                Intent _result = new Intent();
                _result.putExtra("title", marker_title);
                _result.putExtra("snippet", marker_snippet);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, _result);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NewMarkerActivity:

```
    public class NewMarkerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_marker_activity);

        Button save_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
                String marker_title = editName.getText().toString();

                EditText editSnippet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSnippet);
                String marker_snippet = editSnippet.getText().toString();



                Intent _result = new Intent();
                _result.putExtra("title", marker_title);
                _result.putExtra("snippet", marker_snippet);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, _result);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any obvious issues? Help or insight to this problem will be greatly appreciated :)

Here is my output from Logcat:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.geekybrackets.virtualtourguide/com.geekybrackets.virtualtourguide.EditMarkerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: show us the logcats

Comment: Post your logcat to see error

Comment: I hope you have defined your activity in manifest.

Comment: ahhh i think that's what this error is referring to (just updated it). Sorry about that guys, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I hadn't defined the activity in the manifest file.
Dear old me, now i know to check my errors !

Thanks again guys, case closed.

Comment: Hello @J.Tey. Can these two activities work at the same time?